# When do English speakers add /əs/ in the end of a word ending in /əs/?

Tags: english, pronunciation, plurality, possession

What is *the most general and accurate* linguistic observation on when native English speakers add /əs/ in the end when uttering a word already ending in /əs/?

Googling has not helped me one bit.

**Addendum:** I am referring to *both* the plural and the possessive.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Did you look in a dictionary? E.g. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Jesus#Usage_notes

Comment: If you read the usage notes in detail, it links to a discussion of the usage of <'s> vs. <'> with singular proper names ending in s: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%27#Usage_notes.

Comment: Your question is (1) specific to the English language and (2)  unclear as to why the answer at the link I provided is neither general nor accurate enough. Further, it is unclear if you are referring to the possessive -s or the plural.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Your linked-to pages are extraordinarily poor - as well as not answering the OP's question.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Especially the looking in the dictionary suggestion.

Comment: @Araucaria My comments were in reference to the original version of the question (since edited), which did not indicate any research effort. Had I intended my comments to be answers, I would have made them answers.

Answer (score 1):

The question is framed the wrong way: it should be, when do they~we *not* add /z/? First, there are many /z/'s in English -- plural, possessive, reductions of auxiliaries *has, was, is*. Only the possessive enjoys this treatment. Zooming in on the possessive, there are distinct facts of pronunciation and spelling. As for spelling, you'd need to check a current normative grammar of English writing, but I think that you write s-apostrophe in the possessive of a proper name ending in orthographic *s*. However, that doesn't reflect the kind of pronunciation fact where the possessive of (plural) *cats* is pronounced [kæts] and not *[kætsɨz], that is there is actual non-presence of the suffix (Whereas "Jesus' name" is pronounced [dʒɪjzəs̵ɨz]. So this /z+z/ → *z* effect is limited to plural+possessive. It also has to be the /z/ plural, not an irregular plural (*children's, moose's* do not have this reduction).

There is also a semantactic condition, that the noun in question has to be the possessor, so *The cats' feet* only has one /z/. Since the possessive affix is a phrasal affix and goes at the end of an NP, any kind of word can actually manifest the affix, thus "The boy who threw those rocks" can be a possessor, and it is normally *not* subject to this reduction, i.e. "I saw the boy who threw those rocks's [raksɨz] aunt yesterday". Admittedly this is bad writing so you should avoid the problem by using the "N of N" construction, but if you use the structure, do can get plural+possessive. The reason is that "rocks" is not the possessor of "mother", it's the last word in a phrase that is the possessor. Semi-analogously, with conjunctions of nouns in the plural, e.g. *those lions and tigers* plus "'s eyes", I am 60/40 in favor of retaining the possessive (whereas in the above relative clause example, I'm 100% for retention). I don't know of a good experimental study that looks into the details of the variation.

Comment: Re:"Jesus' name" is pronounced [dʒɪjzəs̵ɨz]": The pronunciation [dʒɪjzəs] is also common, and I suspect this anomaly is what OP is referring to.

Comment: You have not answered the OP's question in a constructive and helpful way.